# Ubuntu install rubinius 2.0

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rubinius

I want to try out the new release of rubinius on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine with rvm,
After I run

```
rvm install rbx
```

I get the following

```
rbx-2.0.0 - #install bundler..
Error running 'gem install bundle',
```

The log says

```
You don't have write permissions into the /var/lib/gems/1.9.1 directory.
```

I wish to install this on my user, without any root support, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, Calin it is possible.  How was `rvm` installed?  With `sudo` or as root?  If so, this is why you are seeing this message.  RVM can be installed as a user, and then it will reference your home folders rvm folder instead of the systems.

Comment: @vgoff I have rvm as single user installation

Comment: I have same problem. I installed rvm as a user, I didn't use `sudo`. I haven't figure it out yet.

Comment: Have you checked in #rvm on IRC?  Hopefully @mpapis or another can check this out.

Comment: I did not, but I will, thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @Benjamin I've ended up chown'ing the gem folder to my logged user and it all worked, I don't find this as a right solution so I won't post it as an answer

Comment: If you had to chown your `~/.rvm/.../gem` folder, what did you change it from?  This may be a clue as to what happened.

Comment: @vgoff I've run `chown -R myuser /var/lib/gems/1.9.1` not on my home dir

Comment: Were you using `rvm use system` before you did `rvm install rbx`  Or were you in another rvm ruby?

Comment: I was using `rvm use system` I've setup default on 2.0 prior with `rvm --default use 2.0.0`

Comment: @vgoff if you think is necessary I will load a clean Ubuntu machine and record my steps, it might help debugging

Comment: It couldn't hurt, you will likely answer your own question.  For RVM installations I have done, I have only had the package installed from the OS (usually Ruby 1.8.x) and then then the curl command as indicated on the web page.  Set the default to something other than system and then do `rvm install rbx`  or a lit of rubies.